# PHP Why is "isset()" and "empty()" not working as expected

Tags: php

I have the following if statement,

```
if (isset($_POST['projectName']) && !empty($_POST['projectName']))
```

When the page loads for the very first time, before event hitting the Submit button, the page goes through the if statement and returns false, which is what I intended, but only after someone hits the Submit button.

How can I change it so that it runs through this if statement only after someone hits Submit? Thanks

Comment: This IF statement does not return anything. What do you mean? And how do you detect that "it runs through this if statement"?

Comment: Only fail when `$_POST['projectName']` is set but is also empty, then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if (isset($_POST['projectName']) && !empty($_POST['projectName'])) {
        // ..
    }
}
```

Make sure your form has a submit button with name submit

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
```

Comment: `$_POST['projectname']` will only be set if the form was submitted via POST.

Comment: I have no idea what he wants, so I am asking a few questions. But I see that your answer will not solve the problem, because adding a submit button will not change the situation for this IF statement.

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you. It was my understanding $_POST[] would only occur after someone hit submit?

Comment: @Sven: The submit button alone won’t, but the `if(isset($_POST['submit']))` certainly will.

Comment: @Richard: It will, but any code containing `$_POST` can’t just be automagically skipped. You have to check.

Comment: @Richard: You are right. That's why I wonder that this answer should work.

Comment: @everyone thats the reason why you should understand the question and read the answer properly before down voting a answer. Some one down voted my answer initially . And I have no idea why.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to even evaluate that statement if nothing has been posted you can do it like this:

```
if ('POST' !== $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) { // this is not a POST
    // do something
} else {
    // logic for handling posts
    if(!empty($_POST['projectName']))  {
        //  blah blah blah
    }
}
```

OR

```
if (empty($_POST)) { // this is not a POST
    // do something
} else {
    // logic for handling posts
    if(!empty($_POST['projectName']))  {
        //  blah blah blah
    }
}
```